# AS3 how to manipulate different instances of a class from the timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, class

i am trying to create a menu using as3 and i cant seem to find a way to finish it.
[this is what i got so far](http://www.nurieldesigns.com/1/Untitled-3.html)

so i wrote a class that is attached to a movieclip and i put several instances of it on the stage.

```
package {

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent; 
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.display.*;

public class ServicesButtons extends MovieClip {

    public function ServicesButtons() {

        shapemc.width = 0;

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOff);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);

        function mouseOn(e:Event) {
            var shapeGrow:Tween = new Tween(shapemc, "width", Strong.easeOut, 0, 200, .3, true);
        }

        function mouseOff(e:Event) {
            var shapeShrink:Tween = new Tween(shapemc, "width", Strong.easeOut, shapemc.width, 0, .3, true);
        }

        function clicked(e:Event){
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOff);     
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
        }

    }

}
```

}

I wanted the animation to not roll back once i click on a certain button and i wanted the animation to go back once i click on a different button.

My question is, how do i proceed from here, i searched online for clues and from what i understood i could set variables within the class and change them on the timeline and use event listeners to catch the changes. I tried doing that but i always end up with some redundant way that gets me nowhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to keep which button has been clicked before :

```
public class ServicesButtons extends MovieClip {

    private static var activeButton : ServicesButtons;

    public function ServicesButtons() {
        setListener();
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
    }

    private function mouseOn(e:Event) {
        var shapeGrow:Tween = new Tween(shapemc, "width", Strong.easeOut, 0, 200, .3, true);
    }

    private function mouseOff(e:Event) {
        var shapeShrink:Tween = new Tween(shapemc, "width", Strong.easeOut, shapemc.width, 0, .3, true);
    }

    private function clicked(e:Event){
        if(activeButton != this)
        {
            if(activeButton)
                activeButton.setListener();
            setListener();
            activeButton = this;
        }
    }

    public  function setListener() : void{
            if(hasEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT))
            {
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOff);     
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
            }else{

                addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOn);
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOff);
                mouseOff(null);
            }

    }

}
```